# How to set different commit message for directories and files

Tags: git

I can't figure out how to make a commit to GitHub where directories and data files get different descriptions. Are this kind of commits possible? For example:

```
root_directory/sub_directory/file_1
root_directory/sub_directory/file_2
cd root_directory
```

When committing like this...

```
git commit -m "file_1 description" sub_directory/file_1
git commit -m "file_2 description" sub_directory/file_2
```

... subdirectory and datafiles get the same message and the message of subdirectory is equal to last commit:

```
1) file_1 gets description: "file_1 description"
2) file_2 gets description: "file_2 description"
3) sub_directory gets description: "file_2 description"
```

Or do I have to make 'git init' in every subdirectory and then make commits separately in these subdirectories?

Answer (score 1):

When you commit git apply the commit message to all the files in the index.

If you wish to give different commit to each file(s) simply add them one by one and commit.

```
# Add file 1
git add sub_directory/file_1   

# now your file 1 will get the desired message
git commit -m "file_1 description"

...
# Add file 2
git add sub_directory/file_2 && git commit -m "file_2 description"
```

---

#### In shorts: how git commit work

When you execute `git commit` git take a snapshot of all your files in the index.
 Those files are the ones from the previous commit along with the new/modified ones.

`git commit -m...` simply take the snapshot and generate metadata for it with the following information
[image]

The content of this commit is the following:
[image]

And all those files gets the same commit message

Answer (score 0):

These "descriptions" you're talking about are associated with *commits*, not with individual files or directories. (They're actually called "commit messages" for that reason.)

As far as I know, git does not contain the functionality to associate a description with a file or directory, but that's not really what it's meant for anyway. git is built to help you organize *changes* to files, not so much to help you organize the files themselves. That's part of why you can give a commit (a set of changes) a description, but you can't give an individual file a description.

Incidentally:

> Or do I have to make 'git init' in every subdirectory and then make commits separately in these subdirectories?

I wouldn't recommend that. Having nested git repositories, as you would have if you ran `git init` in every subdirectory, can get fairly complicated and causes more trouble than it's worth unless you're using it for a very specific reason (which would not apply in your case).

Comment: Are you sure you mean “git doesn’t store files, but changes”?

Comment: Did I say that somewhere in my answer? I'm not seeing it, but I could be missing something.

Comment: Second paragraph, second half of first sentence. I had also thought this to be true until fairly recently.

Comment: You mean "...but that's not really what it's meant for anyway"? Or are you talking about the first half of the second sentence, "git tracks changes to files, not the files themselves"? In the latter case, yes, I did mean what I wrote, though now that I look at it again, it could probably be expressed more clearly. I'll edit.

Comment: Ha! I do mean that sentence. Git stores a snapshot of all files in each commit, not changes as I used to think.

Comment: Sure, but I wasn't talking about what git actually _stores_ - that is, I didn't mean to say anything about how it's actually implemented under the hood. What I had in mind was the purpose of git and the workflow you get into when using it, which is centered on changes/change sets rather than individual files. Hopefully that's a little more clear after my edit. (Thanks for the feedback BTW!)